# Why CSS round corner code not working with IE browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, css

```
.style
{
-moz-border-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn to read your CSS instead of blindly copying and pasting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because one of those properties is for Gecko (`-moz-`) browsers, the other is for WebKit (`-webkit-`) browsers.

For IE9 (and Opera 10.50+) you can add the standard declaration:

```
border-radius: 8px;
```

For previous versions you'll have to find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because IE 8 doesn't use -moz- (Mozilla Firefox) nor -webkit- (Chrome, Safari) prefixes and it simply doesn't support CSS 3 yet.

border-radius is part of CSS 3.

Answer (score 1):

For IEs 6->8 I suggest using [CSS3PIE](http://www.css3pie.com).

Answer (score 0):

To do round corners in IE use this jQuery plugin. It draws corners in IE using nested divs (no images). It has native border-radius rounding in browsers that support it (Opera 10.5+, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome). So in those browsers the plugin simply sets a css property on the element

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/